# VB Net: Enable menu/contextmenu items based on security level

Tags: vb.net, security, contextmenu

I have a project with several items that are enabled/disabled based on security level.  I am trying to iterate through all of the controls on the form to get their names and generate a list.  I can get all of the names for the controls and their children but it's not finding all of the context menus I have.  During design I have named all secure items Sec_???.  Here is the code I have so far.  It will find the name of the control and add it to the list.  If it's a binding navigator it will search through the menu items and add any of them that have the Sec tag.  How do I do the same thing for all of my context menus?

```
Public Sub ProcessControls(ByVal ctrlContainer As Control)
    For Each ctrl As Control In ctrlContainer.Controls
        If ctrl.Name.ToString.StartsWith("Sec") Then
            FileOpen(1, "Sec_names.txt", OpenMode.Append)
            PrintLine(1, "**********")
            PrintLine(1, ctrl.Name.ToString & "," & ctrl.GetType.ToString)
            FileClose(1)
        End If
        If TypeOf ctrl Is BindingNavigator AndAlso ctrl.Name.ToString.StartsWith("Sec") Then
            Dim mnuName As BindingNavigator = CType(ctrl, BindingNavigator)
            For i = 0 To mnuName.Items.Count - 1
                Try
                    Dim mnu As ToolStripButton = CType(mnuName.Items(i), ToolStripButton)
                    If mnu.Name.ToString.StartsWith("Sec") Then
                        FileOpen(1, "Sec_names.txt", OpenMode.Append)
                        PrintLine(1, mnu.Name.ToString & "," & mnu.GetType.ToString)
                        FileClose(1)
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            Next
        End If
        ' recursively call this function for the control's children
        If ctrl.HasChildren Then
            ProcessControls(ctrl)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Edit: ProcessControls(Me) is what I use to start the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using

```
For Each vComponent In Me.components.Components
    'Determine if it is component you want process
    'do something with it
Next
```

Be sure it is not empty.. [Why is Me.Components Nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516776/why-is-me-components-nothing)